# "E: Unable to locate package python3-pip"

Tags: python, python-3.x, apt

I am unable to locate package python-pip:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You should show the steps you took to install PIP by including the apt commands you ran to try to install python/pip so that someone can better help you.

Comment: **BEWARE!** Ubuntu's `pip` can cause bizarre conflicts and shouldn't be used for system packages anyway. You might well want a local install of a modern `pip` (version 18 and beyond), and use it only for personal packages with the `--user` option. See [ImportError in system pip wrappers after an upgrade · Issue #5599 · pypa/pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599)

Comment: I am unable to locate package python-pip:" What does this mean? What were you trying to do when this error occurred?

Comment: *All* the answers are missing explanations (they are essentially "try this" answers). *Why* is the change necessary? What is this "universe" thing? Can it be trusted (or to what degree)? What are the implications of the change? May it break something else? What versions of Ubuntu does it work for (or are supposed to)? What version (and edition) of Ubuntu was it tested on? Etc.

Comment: From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*.

Answer (score 63):

For [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), with Python 3.6.5, the `python-pip` package will install after:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

Which is enabling the category `universe`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

Comment: How can this be the "Best answer so far"? The Op asked for Python 3.6.5. This method installs "Python-Pip" which is 2.7!!!!

Comment: it is just working. At least for me. Don't ask me how.

Comment: sudo apt-get python3-pip worked fine after enabling the universe.

Comment: This also works for Ubuntu 20.04. Don't ask me how either.

Comment: What is this "universe" thing? Can it be trusted (or to what degree)?

Answer (score 39):

Following a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 (via [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29)), the following was installed successfully without any issues:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

Note that the Ubuntu 18.04 download today shipped with Python 3.6.8 installed. This may vary by the time of your reading this post.

Comment: This worked for me - I'm using hetzner cloud ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 25):

First update and then install *python3-pip*. So the following two commands should work.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 4):

First run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. If you see *ppa:some repository example launchpad.net not found* or IP address not found, then go to

> ***Software & Updates***, and then unmark the repositories causing the error. Then select the Ubuntu main server, reload and run the commands

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

It will delete unwanted existing packages and clear cache, then
try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

Comment: What tab? The second one, *"Other Software"*?

Answer (score 3):

These commands work for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

This is the old way of installing pip and is especially useful for the old version of Ubuntu.
But still it works fine for me.

Comment: Did not work for me. Clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

You have to clear the unwanted repository's `code  /etc/apt/sources.list` or `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Or another option is switch Ubuntu mirror; see [how to change ubuntu mirror](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682532/how-do-i-switch-to-a-closer-ubuntu-mirror)

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install python3-pip;`

Comment: What do you mean by "clear"? Please add all information to your answer by editing it, instead of putting comments on your own answer

Comment: sorry ,not clean but autoclean will clean unwanted packages and other stuffs basically some respositorys may be outdated or unavailable for downloading using main server respository of ubuntu it will increase your speed check if python2 interpreter is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The other way is adding the **universe** category into the current *sources.list* file directly:

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add the **universe** category at the end of each line:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

Comment: The best answer I would say..... after following several suggestion to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` in many forums, nothing worked..... This is the one that worked finally. I guess this should get the best answer. Basically I moved the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.OLD` and then created fresh with listed above and just updated and continued normally. Everything works like a charm!.... Thanks

Comment: What is this "universe" thing? Can it be trusted (or to what degree)? What is it supposed to contain?